# semantic ui react mobile friendly components

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive, semantic-ui-react

I am using semantic-ui-react for my website. I want to make all the components mobile friendly. But when I look at the website on mobile, all the elements are rendered very small. Please find the image below:

[image]

How do I make elements appear bigger on mobile? Also I want responsive menu for mobile version. Could anyone please let me know ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

do you already have this meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`  in your html? I think it is just missing that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the appropriate `meta` tag in your HTML between `<head></head>` and of course reference the CSS (importing in js is fine too):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.1/dist/semantic.min.css"
/>
```

Comment: Yes, I have added that line. But the components still appear smaller. They are taking the full width, but the height of the input element and font size is very small. Can't even read it.

Comment: I have added it between the <head> tags.
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.1/dist/semantic.min.css"
      />. I am trying to include it in react ssr by the way.

Comment: Can you share an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) via a snippet or link to an [online sandbox](https://codesandbox.io)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Laurens Deprost for the help!

I have fixed this issue. There were 2 problems actually.

The first one was that I was using domain forwarding from godaddy with masking enabled. Due to this entire site was displayed inside a frameset and media queries were not working. To fix this I added a custom domain in Heroku and used that as a CNAME record in godaddy.

Then I also applied css with media queries from here:
https://gist.github.com/phuphighter/ce980aaec1c7104846f7e944743a7e07

With these two fixes in place, the site is working fine.

Thanks